# Django - 'User' object has no attribute 'session_set'

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I want to add a **Sessions** tabs to my Django project:

**navbar.html**

```
 <li><a href="{% url 'user_sessions:session_list' %}">Sessions</a></li>
```

But i keep getting the following error:

```
'User' object has no attribute 'session_set''User' object has no attribute 'session_set'
Exception Location: C:\Users\User\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py in inner, line 214
```

I don't know where this error comes from, i did not find any other reference online, can anyone help me?

Here is the login view that i'm using: https://github.com/Bouke/django-two-factor-auth/blob/master/two_factor/views/core.py

**Full traceback**

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/sessions/

Django Version: 2.1.7
Python Version: 3.7.0
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'main.apps.MainConfig',
 'tinymce',
 'captcha',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django_otp',
 'django_otp.plugins.otp_static',
 'django_otp.plugins.otp_totp',
 'two_factor']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django_otp.middleware.OTPMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\User\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\User\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\User\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\User\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\User\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
  45.         return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\User\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  21.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\User\lib\site-packages\user_sessions\views.py" in dispatch
  22.                                                         **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\User\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\User\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\list.py" in get
  142.         self.object_list = self.get_queryset()

File "C:\Users\User\lib\site-packages\user_sessions\views.py" in get_queryset
  14.         return self.request.user.session_set\

File "C:\Users\User\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py" in inner
  214.         return func(self._wrapped, *args)

File "C:\Users\User\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py" in inner
  214.         return func(self._wrapped, *args)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /account/sessions/
Exception Value: 'User' object has no attribute 'session_set'
```

Comment: You seem to be using this package https://django-user-sessions.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html if so please follow the install instructions

Comment: add `user_sessions` to your installed apps and migrate if you want to use sessions with foreign keys to users. See also the example app's [settings.py](https://github.com/Bouke/django-two-factor-auth/blob/master/example/settings.py)

Comment: Yes! Thank you both! I suspected it was an import error, but since i noticed that i already had a Session module on my INSTALLED_APPS, i was not able to figure out what i was missing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace `django.contrib.sessions` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` with `user_sessions` if you want to use django-user-sessions. This will setup its models correctly.

Furthermore make sure you have also followed all other [installation instructions](https://django-user-sessions.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html).

Comment: Indeed, my error was to use django.contrib.sessions instead of django-user-sessions. Installing and adding to my INSTALLED_APPS django-user-sessions worked!

Comment: do you know how to import Session class from user_sessions ?